# Jquery Flipswitch toggle for webapplication

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I need flipswitch toggle for webapplication. 
I tried with existing scripts but it's changing all my page view into mobile view.

I need to implement flipswitch for webapplication with 2 options i.e; Histotic data and realtime data.

Please help me on this .

Comment: Questions without much info are generally voted down for close, so if you want not to be closed consider improving your question with what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](https://api.jquerymobile.com/flipswitch/) it is an jquery mobile controll you can use in Webapplication also

You can use following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>
/* Custom indentations are needed because the length of custom labels differs from
   the length of the standard labels */
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch .ui-btn.ui-flipswitch-on {
    text-indent: -4em;
}
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch .ui-flipswitch-off {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
/* Custom widths are needed because the length of custom labels differs from
   the length of the standard labels */
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch {
    width: 8.875em;
}
.custom-size-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch.ui-flipswitch-active {
    padding-left: 7em;
    width: 1.875em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <label for="switch">Flip Toggle Switch:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch">
        <br>
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: it's working fine but by using this alignment of other controls in this page is changing.

Comment: Yes, CSS must be conflicting. Do one thing Download the `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css` and only use the css which is required for flipswitch and delete the other css.It may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. Now its working fine.